# Android:Full screen not working

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

I cant get my activity to display as full screen. In my manifest file i have added

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Am i missing something??

Comment: Do you have a custom title in ActivityName?

Answer (score 0):

It looks very similar to what works for me, except I do it on the application tag eg.

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I think you can set programmaticly like this as well however I have not done this way

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

EDIT

here is a full layout of a fullscreen test app i threw together

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.xxx.fullscreen"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".fullscreenActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: well sounds like you have something restricting it from going full Screen in the first place, those are the recommended calls for enabling fullscreen. What SDK level are you targeting / using to test? and is this occurring on the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: i m trying it on api8. it happens both on the device n emulator

Comment: i know it may sounds silly but i have had luck fixing layout issues like this by simply moving around where i put the property. so try a few spots in the <application > area and the <activity >. Besides that I would say create a test case with just using your layout on a blank application and see if you can get it to work. If it does work then somewhere else in your code is restricting this functionality

Comment: i think the problem might be in my linearlayout inside scrollview that i m using in my activity. there are [link]couple(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview) of questions on those on SO...will take a look at those and post my findings..thxs

Comment: My layout included scrollview,linearlayout & tablelayout. Once i removed the linearlayout it seem to work ok. I think it was something to do with the settings on the linearlayout ...maybe it was an overkill having so many layers when all i want is to arrange my widgets in a table..

Answer (score 0):

Check the activity you are trying to make full screen if its extending ActionBar or AppCompatActivity??? Change it to Activity instead of ActionBar or AppCompatActivity. Then try.

```
"public class WelcomeScreen extends Activity {
         //Code
}
"
```