# Why would I get an error on a comment?

Tags: android, android-layout

Why would I get, "error:Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

on this line (which is a comment):

```
<!-- added fillViewport as preventive measure after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview -->
```

?

Comment: could we get more context? I've run only the comment through a validator and there were no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna guess you added that comment in the middle of a tag. You can't do that. This is wrong:

```
  <ScrollView
     android:... <!-- this won't work -->
     android:...
  >
  </ScrollView>
```

Just move it to be outside of the < and >.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the dashes in the URL. Try showing all non-printable characters in your text editor, as you may have copied a control character.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comment and type it back by hand. You most probably have unprintable characters in there.