# LinearLayout does not fill the scrollview

Tags: layout, android, android-gui

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The scrollview fill the whole screen but the linearLayout1 fill just small part of the screen something near 100dip in height. How can I make the linearLayout1 to fill the parent ?

Comment: are you sure the scrollview fills the screen? Did you try fillViewport="true" in the scrollview ?

Comment: See this link http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html

Comment: Giving android:fillViewport="true" in Scrollview will work..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with :

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

on the **scrollView**

More information here: [LinearLayout not expanding inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have ListView in ScrollView.