# Android Scroll View last view not showing inside linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created a Scroll view and it contains some Linear layouts that contains some views ***but issue is that the last view is not showing inside scroll view My Linear layout is not expending*** and **android:fillViewport="true"** is not working, i will post screen shot 
MY Output is

MY XML CODE IS

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_filters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2f3f9f"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="FILTERS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_filters"
        android:background="#202231" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#202231"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/open_now"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Opne Now"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_open_now"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/smoking_inside"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Smoking Inside"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_smoking_inside"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shots"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Shots"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_shots"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vvip"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="VVIP"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_vvip"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/terrace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Terrace"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_terrace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#2a2d41" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/karoake"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Karaoke"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_karoake"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cigar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Cigar"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_cigar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vip"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="VIP"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_vip"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sea_side"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Sea Side"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_sea_side"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/swimming_pool"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Swimming Pool"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_swimming_pool"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#2a2d41" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/music_selection_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_music"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Music"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_music_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_music_fonts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cuisine_layouts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_cuisines"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Cuisines"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_cuisines_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_cuisines_fonts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/outlet_type_layouts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_type"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Type"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_type_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_type_fonts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/filter_cover_charges_upto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="COVER CHARGES UPTO"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/filter_cover_charges_upto_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:paddingRight="4dp"
                        android:text="50"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar_value_min"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:max="999" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="999"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#2a2d41"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_guest_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="GUESTLIST UPTO"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:text="23:30"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_arrow_fonts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activate_plans_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2f3f9f"
            android:text="SUBMIT"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2606641/2798289

Comment: i have give android:fillViewport="true" but it is not working,

Comment: add alignBottom to wrapper_button for scrollView , now the last item of scroll view is under button

Comment: i am not understating  , can you explore a bit more?

Comment: Add this to your ScollView : android:layout_above="@id/wrapper_button"

Comment: ListView ? i don't have any Listview in my UI?

Comment: Sorry I mean ScrollView :)))

Comment: not working , i have tried it. ?

Comment: @user12345 Some Where You have Put layout_height=" fill_parent" you have use Remove that and put wrap_content

Comment: Move wrapper_button tag to before the ScrollView and then add android:layout_above="@id/wrapper_button" to your scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change height of ScrollView to wrap content or you can also put your ScrollView and the last LinearLayout into another LinearLayout having vertical orientation with fill_parent dimensions and add the weight property to both of them.

Comment: I would suggest the second thing you said, it is a good option. But it should be match_parent instead of the deprecated fill_parent just to be picky

Comment: In my case, was enough to just "Change height of ScrollView to wrap content". Cool - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your last Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#2a2d41"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_guest_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="GUESTLIST UPTO"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="23:30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_arrow_fonts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text=">"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not the best solution to add margin_bottom for fixing thisi issue