# Navigation drawer Layout doesn't take full height even though specified

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I would like my button to be at the bottom of my layout but it doesn't seem to be working. Somehow it's stuck at the middle of my screen and it won't go down... code below. My main `LinearLayout` seems to have a `match_parent` height though...

```
<ScrimInsetsScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:background="@color/navdrawer_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/chosen_account_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_chosen_account_height"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <!--android:foreground="?photoItemForeground"-->
            <!-->-->

            <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_foodie_nav_image"
                android:tint="@color/session_photo_scrim"
                android:id="@+id/profile_cover_image"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:id="@+id/chosen_account_content_view"
                android:onClick="showProfile">

                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_profile_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_profile_image_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_accounts_expand" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_email_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/body_text_2_inverse"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_name_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/profile_email_text"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                    android:textColor="@color/body_text_1_inverse"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <!-- Account items -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/account_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navdrawer_items_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/red_500"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrimInsetsScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in that post [LinearLayout not expanding inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview)

> Found the solution myself in the end. The problem was not with the
>   LinearLayout, but with the ScrollView (seems weird, considering the
>   fact that the ScrollView was expanding, while the LinearLayout
>   wasn't).
>
> The solution was to use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView.

Just use it on the Scrimset