# Setting minimum height of a view to be the height of its parent

Tags: java, android

Inside a ScrollView I have a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout can be as tall as it wants, but I want its minimum height to be at least as tall as its parent (the ScrollView).

```
<ScrollView
    ...>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/some_margin"
        android:minHeight="match_parent">
```

This does not work. It won't accept `"match_parent"` for `minHeight`. So how do I approach this?

Comment: I would use `setMinimumHeight(int)` from Java

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2606641/2308683

Answer (score 8):

You could use the ScrollView's `android:fillViewport="true"` property in the xml file like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Rest of the children-->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This makes the ScrollView tall, but not the inner element (LinearLayout).

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to avoid having wasted real estate when the stuff in the LinearLayout doesn't fill up the space allowed by the ScrollView? How about just setting LinearLayout height to:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You could set the same on the ScrollView so that it fits its own parent as well, but not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 this should work. Are you sure elements in the linear layout take free space? i.e. weight set

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you show a sample code?

Comment: Derek- if you include the full layout XML and a screenshot of what you get and explain what's wrong with it, we should be able to help.