# TableLayout being truncated when placed inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout which is populated dynamically with many rows of data. It contains more data than the screen can hold, so I require it to be scrollable.

My issue is that when I place the TableLayout inside of a ScrollView, it appears to cut off many rows from the top of the TableLayout.

For reference, the full code is here (the question is to cluttered already to fit it all) http://pastebin.com/w7Fi3Bzz

See below for the code related to the issue I'm having

Here is the XML without the ScrollView:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/tbl_statistics"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            >
        </TableLayout>
```

And what it looks like:

[image]

And here is the same XML with an enclosing ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/tbl_statistics"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            >
        </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And here is what the table looks like, you can see the top of the table was truncated (it is populated with the same exact data):

[image]

I found a similar issue here [LinearLayout not expanding inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview), but the answers did not help me.

Comment: You don't need the `LinearLayout` in your second layout.

Comment: @MikeM. This issue persists whether I include it or not

Comment: I second @MikeM. the `LinearLayout` is redundant. You should make `layout_height` of `TableLayout` to `wrap_content` when you remove the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Try removing the `layout_gravity` attribute in the `TableLayout`, without the `LinearLayout`. Also, the `fillViewport` is useless on anything other than a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Alright guys I will remove it to simplfy my question but I've tried it both ways and it still truncates

Comment: @MikeM. I've tried removing the layout_gravity tag (and I've also removed the LinearLayout). I still get the same results

Comment: I would guess, then, that the top of the `ScrollView` is under another `View`, as you've got its `layout_height` at `fill_parent`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, it is enclosed within a LinearLayout for the activity shown in this app, along with the Spinners and Button you can see in the image. Would it be useful to add that? The question already has so much code and images.

Comment: Well, before posting the whole thing, try setting the `ScrollView`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and its `layout_weight` to `1`.

Comment: @MikeM. No luck trying that. I've also edited my answer to include the full code for my activity layout. thanks for your help so far

Comment: Tested and verified again. If that doesn't solve your problem, then you'll need to post the code that's generating the table, and any code that might modify the `TableLayout`'s `LayoutParams`. Really, the crux of your problem is the `TableLayout`'s `layout_gravity` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [current layout](http://pastebin.com/w7Fi3Bzz):

1. Remove `android:layout_gravity="center"` from the `TableLayout` element.
2. Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the `ScrollView` element.
3. Clean and rebuild your project.

Additionally, the `fillViewport` attribute only works on `ScrollView`s.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: I will award my bounty I first want to deploy my application and verify it works in production. Thank you for all the help over the last 2 days.

Comment: No problem! Sorry you had to spend 50 rep. I'd've come back to help for nothin'. :-) Just happened to see your question in the bounties. Hope it finally fixes it for ya everywhere. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same issue only by inserting TableLayout into LinearLayout which is only child of ScrollView. I tried all other variants without success (`fillViewport` for `ScrollView`, `android:layout_weight="1"` for `TableLayout`).

I used `TableLayout` to dynamically insert `Views` to it

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_displayFields_tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```