# Android ChatActivity Bottom LinearLayout covers bottom of ScrollView scrollable area

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a chat Activity that has a send message box at the bottom. The send message box should always be visible and always be at the bottom of the screen. The Scrollview has a vertical LinearLayout that has views added to it inside of a loop. It works pretty much perfectly except when the there are enough views in the LinearLayout to make it scrollable the last element is always covered by the send message box. If I make the send message box invisible you can see all of the views in the layout. See images for clarity.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE A ListView because I don't want to have to use an adapter

This image on the left shows the last item being covered. Then making the send message invisible shows the last element.

[image]                                     [image]

Here's the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_chat" tools:context="com.example.brian.cleverrent.ChatActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/chatTimeLineLayout">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
            android:layout_weight=".9"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/chatSendButton"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try using

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

for the ScrollView. Haven't tested it myself, but it was proposed as a solution to a similar problem here [LinearLayout not expanding inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview).

Comment: Using a combination of your answer and adding padding to the bottom of the scrollview fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add...

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

Thanks to Nestel for answer